# How to convert a Pandas dataframe to Excel?

Tags: excel, pandas, dataframe, export-to-excel

I have a pandas DF composed of the following columns, and converted to Excel:
[Overview Data Frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dq7ov.jpg)

This is an overview of the EC2 Instances of my AWS Account.
I am trying to obtain some statistics through this code:

```py
summary = pd.DataFrame(ec2_list.groupby(['State','AvailabilityZone'])['State'].count())
```

When I try to print the content of the summary variable, I get this console output:

```
print(summary)
output:

                         State
State   AvailabilityZone       
running eu-central-1a        14
        eu-central-1b         1
stopped eu-central-1a         6
        eu-central-1b         9
```

I tried to append this Dataframe to the initial one (see above) and apply `to_excel()` method on it, so that I can get the EC2 Information and the summary on the same sheet.

However, I only get the information under the `state` column appended to my sheet, but the other information are not displayed.

Example of the output under the state column:

```
 State

running
stopped
running
running 
   .
   .
   .
  14 
   1
   6
   9
```

and the other piece of information

```
State   AvailabilityZone       
running eu-central-1a        
        eu-central-1b         
stopped eu-central-1a         
        eu-central-1b
```

are not displayed on the final sheet.

Can anyone help me so that I could resolve this problem ? Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code for how you're appending the summary dataframe?

Comment: of course:
ec2_list = ec2_list.append(summary, ignore_index=False, sort=True)